# Get Windows startup programs in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, startup

I'm writing a performance assistant in batch, and ran in to a bit of a problem. One of the modes of the script would find your startup items, and selectively disable the ones that have a harmful impact on boot times. The problem is, I can't find a way to do this. The specific items I am looking for are the programs listed under MSConfig, under the Startup tab. 
Direct question: Is it possible to retrieve the list of start up items on say Windows 7, compare them to a list of known programs that cause long boot times, then disable them without affecting all of the startup programs without user interaction outside of starting the script and selecting the mode?

Comment: `wmic startup get` you use a `for /f` loop to parse command output. See `wmic /?`, `wmic startup /?`, `wmic startup get /?`, `wmic startup call /?`, `wmic /format /?`. Use `reg /?` to edit the registry.

Comment: That only partially answers the question. I still need a way to compare the output of "startup get" with a predetermined list of programs, then edit the registry for only the programs that are prepopulated.

Comment: Define `startup items`. Windows starts a number of processes automatically, from different places for different reasons. See for example [AutoRuns/sc](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) and its help file.

Comment: The programs listed in MSConfig, under "startup".

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this :

```
@echo off
Set LogFile=%~n0.txt
If exist %LogFile% Del %LogFile%
wmic /APPEND:%LogFile% STARTUP get /format:list>Nul
Start "" %LogFile%
```

Comment: While this is a valid answer, it isn't quite what I had in mind. Your answer would require parsing the new file with the batches predefined list, and simultaneously running the batch. As (in my particular case), I require the script to keep running and perform more things after it does the startup cleaning process.